# How to set shortcut in vim for specific file name?

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I have

```
" Rspec Shortcuts
nnoremap <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec rspec % --fail-fast<cr>

" Minitest Shortcuts
nnoremap <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec ruby -w -Itest %<cr>
```

I want to enable these shortcuts to be conditioned with the file name.

I have tried setting the condition like this:

```
if @% =~ '*_spec.rb'
  nnoremap <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec rspec % --fail-fast<cr>
endif

if @% =~ '*_test.rb'
  nnoremap <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec ruby -w -Itest %<cr>
endif
```

But it did not work.
Without the conditions the shortcuts are working of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

- Use buffer local mappings by adding `<buffer>`
- Set these mappings up on only specific file names probably via an `:autocmd`

The mappings will look like the following:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec rspec % --fail-fast<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec ruby -w -Itest %<cr>
```

Now you need to load these mappings for specific `FileType`'s or filenames:

```
augroup RubyTestMappings
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *_spec.rb nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec rspec % --fail-fast<cr>
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *_test.rb nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec ruby -w -Itest %<cr>
augroup END
```

Another other option would be to put these mappings into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim` like so:

```
if @% =~ '*_spec.rb'
  nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec rspec % --fail-fast<cr>
endif

if @% =~ '*_test.rb'
  nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :!clear; bundle exec ruby -w -Itest %<cr>
endif
```

For more help see:

```
:h :map-local
:h :autocmd
:h BufNewFile
:h BufRead
```